# Proof that if $0 \lt a \lt 1$ and $r \lt s$, then $a^{r} \gt a^{s}$. $r, s \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm learning pre-calculus, and I'm struggling to prove some sentences, I managed to prove the sentence to $a \gt 1$, but for $0 \lt a \lt 1$ i'm struggling, could someone show me how I start?

For $a > 1$ i did this:

$$t = s -r$$
$$a^{s} = a^{r+t} = a^{r} * a^{t}$$
$$a^{s} \gt a^{r}$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice if $s=r+t$ we have:
$$a^r-a^{r+t}>0\to a^r(1-a^t)>0$$
$$\to a^r(1-a)\sum_{n=0}^{t-1}a^n>0$$
For $0<a<1$, it should be fairly straightfoward to show that each element in the last expression is positive.

---

In case of confusion:

$$(1-a^t)=(1-a)(1+a+a^2+...+a^{t-1})=(1-a)\sum_{n=0}^{t-1}a^n$$